# how to add white color to wxpython box

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to add a white color to the thickness box which is currently appearing as grey as in the image. Any help to solve

[image]

Below is the code

```
sbSizer4 = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self.m_panel_geometry, wx.ID_ANY, u"Thickness" ), wx.VERTICAL )
sbSizer4.Add( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
m_thicknessChoices = [ u"0.062 in", u"0.031 in" ]
self.m_thickness = wx.Choice( sbSizer4.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_thicknessChoices, 0 )
self.m_thickness.SetSelection( 0 )
#self.m_thickness.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(240, 0, 240)) 
sbSizer4.Add( self.m_thickness, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 15 )
sbSizer4.Add( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
bSizer11.Add( sbSizer4, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10 )
bSizer9.Add( bSizer11, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
bSizer12 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to realise that:

- Your code was not indented properly (not helped by another edit)
- You're using a `StaticBox` within a `StaticBoxSizer`
- You must be using an older version of wxPython

Try removing one of the static boxes, there seems little to be gained from having 2 of them, whilst only labeling one.
You specify white in the question but in the code you attempted a vile puce/pink colour, I've run with that ;).

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title="Static Box"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("palegreen")

        bSizer9 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        sbSizer4 = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL, panel, "Thickness")
        sbSizer4.Add( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        m_thicknessChoices = [ u"0.062 in", u"0.031 in" ]
        self.m_thickness = wx.Choice( sbSizer4.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_thicknessChoices, 0 )
        self.m_thickness.SetSelection( 0 )
        self.m_thickness.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(240, 0, 240)) 
        sbSizer4.Add( self.m_thickness, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sbSizer4.Add( ( 0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        bSizer11.Add( sbSizer4, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10 )
        bSizer9.Add( bSizer11, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        panel.SetSizer(bSizer9)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    TestFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing wx.Choice() with BitmapComboBox() and style=wx.CB_READONLY fixed the color issue for me. There's some odd fading in and out when changing the selection though (at least on  Win 10). wxPython is really good at making simple things hard.